# How to get document fields using API (SDK)?

Tags: kofax

I am trying to get the list of all document field properties by document ID. I am bit lost how to send the correct parameters. Kofax Help article says to use GetDocumentFieldPropertyValues (string sessionId, ReportingData reportingData, string documentId, **FieldPropertiedCollections fieldProperties**).

Can someone help me  how to pass the correct value of filePropertiesCollection which consists of RunTimeFieldIdentity and FieldSystemPropertyIdentity? I am getting exception whenever I pass runTImeFieldIdentity as Name = "Height". May be it is not clear which value to pass?

Any sample working code will be very helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer my own question 75% :)

After doing more research finally I ended up using CaptureDocumentService.GetDocument method which will fetch all the required information about runtime fields. By saying what I have noticed the runtime **values** are being overwritten in my process. Any idea KOFAX gurus ?

Answer (score 0):

can you please be more explicit to try to understand well your need, and the problem that do you have?.
If it's possible try to upload an image to clarify.

Bye

Comment: I have created an upload job with extraction group and associated fields using API. I was trying to get the FieldProperties collections of the extraction group. I was stuck. But when I used GetDocument method i was able to get the information. One thing i noticed when we classify the document all my field values are being overwritten. Is this by design?